# Recover a MicroSD memory

Tags: memory, data-recovery, file-format, micro-sd-card

I connected my MicroSD Memory to a computer and when the computer was reading data from it, I suddenly removed it from the computer.

Now there is no files in memory and it's empty **BUT** `My Computer` shows used space correctly which means files still exists in memory. I tried to recover it with a software called `Recover My Files` but it could recover only 46 photos (of 500 photos). So is it possible to recover all contents of memory? Those photos are very important.

here is a picture of my `My Computer`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaay! My problem just solved! using [TestDisk & PhotoRec 6.14](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download).